# foreach to while loop conversion in dataset asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

How to convert following foreach loop in while loop

```
foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        temp_data = temp_data + ................
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to avoid both `foreach` and `while` by using LINQ. As you haven't revealed the `................`, it's difficult to show you how though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the enumerators of the collections like this:

```
IEnumerator enum1 = ds.Tables.GetEnumerator();
while (enum1.MoveNext())
{
    IEnumerator enum2 = ((DataTable)enum1.Current).Rows.GetEnumerator();
    while (enum2.MoveNext())
    {
        temp_data = temp_data + ((DataRow)enum2.Current)[0];
    }
}
```

But I suggest LINQ expressions:

```
string temp_data = (from DataTable dataTable in ds.Tables select dataTable)
    .SelectMany(o => from DataRow dataRow in o.Rows select dataRow[0])
    .Aggregate(string.Empty, (qs, q) => qs = qs + q);
```

Br,
Márton